# Convert string "nan" to numpy NaN in pandas Dataframe that contains Strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a file into a dataframe and I see many of my columns contain "nan" strings. Wherever appropriate I have used,

```
data[['price','age']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

But there are other columns that contain "string" values.

I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
data['address'].replace('nan', '')
```

How can I convert "nan" values in columns that containg Strings to NaN or empty string or N/A . Basically some value which will be convenient for me to check if a  value is present or not.

Edit: Including minimal verifiable code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dict = {'col-a': ['value-a', 'nan', 'nan'],
        'col-b': ['34', '35', '36'],
        'col-c': ['24', '25', '26']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df,"\n")
df[['col-b','col-c']] = df[['col-b','col-c']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
# does not work
df.replace('nan','')
# does not work
df.replace('nan',np.nan)
print(df,"\n")
```

Comment: Check dupe answers, if not working let me know.

Comment: Hi, I don't have null strings. I have "nan" as a values where there should be null strings. I need a null string or NaN or something in place of the string "nan".

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Hi JEZRAEL, I have edited the question to include the code. Thank You

Comment: Sure, working on solution.

Comment: For me working nice `df = df.replace('nan','')`

Comment: ok....thanks. I check again.